# Creating a keytab on Windows for Kerberos authentication on Linux

Tags: windows, kerberos

I need to run curl commands from a Windows server to an API on a Linux box. When I am on my workstation I just run a kinit and give my user name and pwd for the Kerberos realm. 
I have automated scripts in which I need to run a kinit before running the Powershell script. I do not want any manual intervention. I am trying to create a keytab file with my Kerberos account but it is not working - 
I am receiving the error message "No key table entry found for user@domain.net while getting initial credentials. 
I really don't understand much about Kerberos, and whether the process cares that I am on a Windows server tryng to use a keytab file for this purpose. 
Can someone help? I have been going a bit nuts with this... 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Look into your keytab if the principal there is the one you are going to use. `klist -k -t <keytab>`

Comment: this command klist -k -t blah.keytab does not work - message is klist -k -t blah.keytab

Usage: klist.exe [command]

Command list:
  [tickets] [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
  tgt [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
  purge [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
  sessions [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
  kcd_cache [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
  get <SPN> [-lh <LogonId.HighPart>] [-li <LogonId.LowPart>]
            [-kdcoptions <options>]
  add_bind <DOMAIN> <DC>
  query_bind

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously doing wrong. You have to obtain a curl binary for Windows which says with `curl --version`:

```
curl 7.46.0 ...
Protocols: http https ...
Features: SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO ...
```

That's it. Enable SPNEGO auth with `curl --negotiate -u : <URL>` and you are done. No keytab necessary on Windows.

Comment: curl 7.41.0 (i686-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.41.0 WinSSL
Protocols: http https
Features: Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO SSL                                  The problem is that I have to run a kinit before I perform the curl.

Comment: @user3429443, this version uses GSS-API instead of SSPI. Get a version compiled with SSPI.